# Relation between tables

Tags: sql

```
Person Table
-------------------------------------
PersonId   |   Name   |   Surname   |
-------------------------------------
1              John       Smith
2              Sam        Rainbow


Address Table
------------------------------------------
AddressId   |   PersonId   |   Address   |
------------------------------------------
1               1              AAA
2               1              BBB
```

so what I want to do is, If I execute the query below,

```
DELETE Person WHERE PersonId = 1
```

SQL should not allow me to delete from Person table since there are rows related to that Person in Address table.

How can I create this relation?

Comment: you want the DBMS (SQL Server,MYSQL,...) to return an error or you just don't want your query to delete anything (without error from DBMS)

Comment: Which one do you think is more beneficial?

Comment: @BonusKun : try my answer..!! it solves your case..!!

Comment: I always prefer the DBMS to return the error. It always prevents any execution due to possible bugs in the software. In that case i would advise you to use a Forgein Key with References. Many examples of that can be found below.

Comment: @BonusKun if you add Foreignkey,it does not prevent the other table data from deletion,but deletes both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE Address
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PersonId)
REFERENCES Person (PersonId)
```

Comment: It would be good practice to *name* the foreign key constraint.

Comment: this does not prevent the other table data from deletion,but deletes both..!!

Comment: @SajadLfc only if you enable cascade deletes (which I don't if I can at all avoid it)

Answer (score 1):

Add a foreign key constraint and restrict deletes:

```
ALTER TABLE Address
ADD CONSTRAINT Address_PersonId_fkey
FOREIGN KEY (PersonId)
REFERENCES Person (PersonId)
ON DELETE RESTRICT  -- what you asked for
ON UPDATE CASCADE;  -- maybe do something different for updates?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DELETE Address WHERE PersonId = 1
```

after that

```
DELETE Person WHERE PersonId = 1
```

or you can reference in Address table

```
ALTER TABLE Address
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PersonId)
REFERENCES Person (PersonId)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PersonId` of `Person` should be `PRIMARY KEY` and `PersonId` of `Address` table should be `FOREIGN KEY` which should `REFERENCE PersonId of Person`.  If this relation exists between these two tables, then automatically the DBMS will return error on deleting a record from Person table if the ID exists in Address table.

The below SQL will alter your tables.

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD PRIMARY KEY (PersonId)

ALTER TABLE Address
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PersonId)
REFERENCES Persons(PersonId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,this will solve your case

> SQL should not allow me to delete from Person table since there are
>   rows related to that Person in Address table

```
 DECLARE @CNT AS BIGINT
    SELECT @CNT=ISNULL(COUNT(PersonId),0) FROM Address where PersonId=1 


    IF @CNT=0
        BEGIN
            DELETE Person WHERE PersonId = 1
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create primary key and foreign key relationships in these tables, this will prevent deleteing records from Person if there are corresponding entries in Address table.

```
CREATE TABLE Person
    (
    PersonId INT CONSTRAINT pk_person_pid PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(25),
    Surname VARCHAR(25)
    );


    CREATE TABLE Address
    (
    AddressId INT CONSTRAINT pk_address_aid PRIMARY KEY,
    PersonId INT CONSTRAINT fk_personAddress_pid FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(PersonId),
    AddressVARCHAR(25)
    );
```

[Reference: creating primary key, foreign key constraints](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/08/sql-server-%E2%80%93-2008-creating-primary-key-foreign-key-and-default-constraint/)